# Как управлять выходом dynamic import?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babel, ssr

Привет я делаю ssr отдельным скриптом. В моем приложении есть импорт сторонних библиотек которые не могут исполняться в ssr среде. Поэтому я разделил выходящий bundle с помощью dynamic imports. Все получилось, ssr скрипт работает. Но клинский скрипт который генерируется из того же кода теперь тоже имеет раздельный выход.
Примерно такого вида:

```
  dist/js/609.min.js           222.04 KiB                                                                                     89.65 KiB
  dist/js/app.min.js           125.74 KiB                                                                                     74.42 KiB
  dist/js/297.min.js           77.42 KiB                                                                                     46.70 KiB
  dist/js/254.min.js           104.45 KiB                                                                                     35.81 KiB
  dist/js/33.min.js            1.15 KiB                                                                                      32.12 KiB
  dist/js/632.min.js           23.28 KiB                                                                                      30.88 KiB
  dist/js/727.min.js           121.12 KiB                                                                                      30.79 KiB
  dist/css/app.5585fc9b.css    145.54 KiB                                                                                     24.78 KiB
```

Я пробовал менять babel.preset

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset', { modules: false }]]
}
```

Но безуспешно. Какой параметр влияет на splitchunks dynamic imports, мне необходим раздельный вывод для ssr и объединенный для клиенского